# Does FogzBugz have an API?

Tags: fogbugz

Does FogBugz offer a developer API for interacting with party applications? If so, where can I find documentation on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try here: [FogBugz XML API version 8](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/fogbugz-xml-api)

Comment: That would have made my migration task a lot easier!  I guess it wasn't around at the time for the version we were using

Comment: @tonycoupland: FogBugz XML API is there since FogBugz 5 :-)

Comment: I think I originally wrote it against FB5, but I guess rather than look for an API I just hacked straight into the DB :) ... typical coder

Comment: @tonycoupland: let's be fair to you ... in FB5, XML API was far from complete ... furthermore, FogBugz has well-documented DB schema, so using DB directly was probably better choice :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an API, but the SQL Server database is reasonably easy to navigate.  I have written tools to extract entries from Fogbugz and insert them into a timesheet system.